# Aquaris E45 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch

I have an Aquaris E45 with only Ubuntu-touch on it. It's quite buggy at this time (GPS, freez, network issue ....) is there a way to have android too on it?

Answer (score 2):

I finally hard reset my BQ aquaris E45 with android only.

The ubuntu touch was too bugy, location very hasardous, missing calls, some calls not loged, cannot receive MMS, network issue while taking the train...

Comment: apparently there's a way to do dual boot: stackoverflow.com/questions/30549563/android-dual-boot-on-bq-ubuntu-touch